In E-MOSFET, how is $V_{DSsat}=V_{GS}-V_T$?

In an electronics book by R Boylestad,it is given that for an E-MOSFET if $V_{DS}$ increases,for constant $V_{GS}$,$V_{GD}$ decreases which means Drain is more positive than Gate and hence reduces the attractive forces on electrons and therby reducing n channel width.It obviously doesnot make sense to me as drain bieng relatively positive than Gate doesnot mean Gate's potential has dropped.So for me it is the more reverse bias at Drain that is causing channel to shrink(depletion region gets wider).What is more irritating to me is that i cant get how He wrote $V_{DSsat}=V_{GS}-V_T$?

Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

@Qmechanic how can i crosspost it?any shortcut?or i have to write and post it again?

To see the (simplified) physical model behind this, you can imagine the channel chopped up into infinitesimal MOSFETs connected in series, with all their gates connected together. You'd expect that for each small element $V_{GS}$ approaches $0$ in the large-$N$ limit. But if you solve it, along the chain the voltage indeed goes up in small steps, until the last element which will act as a bottle neck getting a large part of the voltage! (The space here is too small to give the details, and of course there are more complicated models than this "$1$D" model.)

@JosBergervoet Can u illustrate this with diagram please?

Of course: https://i.sstatic.net/bth17.jpg , but the real challenge will be to find the 1D differential equation for the voltage shape along the sequence. (If you solve it you'll find some square root shaped function!)
